# How to know when a process exited?

Tags: android, process, android-logcat

I have a process that outputs log.
But that process exited in Samsung device sometimes.
I want to recreate process if that process exited.
I can check whether process exited or not by using following code.

```
if (process.toString().contains("hasExited=true, exitcode=1")) {
    // recreate process
}
```

Now I want to know is that is there any callback function that are called when process exited.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the Process exits I think it's caused by the System due to low memory/resources (or due to inactivity in some situations). Does the Process belongs the same App you're creating as a Monitor for that process, or it's a different APK? There isn't any callback/event if a process exits due to a Kill() command by the System, so if the Process is yours you could create a one-way continously communication between the Process and your Monitor-App. In this way when the Monitor-App doesn't receive any data from that Process it should consider as killed.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I think the process is mine. It is not from different APK. Can you tell me the links about your advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What links? I think you have to choose the best "IPC" (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) way to communicate between processes based on your skill in development. I think the best solution is to use "Pipes" but I don't know if you know them.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think it's advanced level for me. I need to learn more deeply.